# Как отключить автозапуск программы при старте Mandriva 2009?

Tags: mandriva, автозапуск

На работе поставили компьютер под управлением Mandriva 2009. Стартует сразу служебная программа мониторинга больных. А посмотреть фильм, послушать музыку? Как побороть сие зло? Мы в Linux-e ламеры. Если можно ответить подробно. Юрий.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой выход из положения - это после вынужденного автозапуска приложения переключиться на другой рабочий стол (по умолчанию делается горячими клавишами Ctrl + Alt + стрелка). Если это неудобно, то посмотреть

- `~/.kde/Autostart/`
- `/user/share/autostart`

если там есть скрипт на запуск вашего приложения и права позволяют, удалить его. Кроме того, можно заглянуть в меню `Configure your Desktop >Advanced>Autostart` и отключить там приложение (если оно там есть).